# How i can draw a horizontal line on my Plaster Jar? using paining tape or stencil?

Tags: painting, paint, tape

I have built this Jar using Plaster:-

[image]

And i paint it with plastic white paint as a base >> then apply this gold metallic paint.. now i want to paint some horizontal brown lines using oil-based brown paint and a small brush.. But need some idea and help on how i can get a perfect horizontal line/s? I think it will be hard to do so using painting tape (by tapping 2 parallel horizontal lines using painting tape and keep like 10 cm between them, then paint the area between the 2 tapes ), as it will be hard to maintain equal space between the 2 parallel tapes + i will have a risk of removing or damages the gold paint after removing the tape.. so is there another idea to do so? and are there any online stencils that i can order which can help me in doing what i need?

Thanks

Comment: you're asking at the wrong place ... the question belongs at https://crafts.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jsotola i am asking about painting ,,, and seems there are tags for them in this forum

Answer (score 3):

Get a [turntable](https://www.amazon.com/painting-turntable/s?k=painting%20turntable) and a [holding clamp](https://www.google.com/search?q=electronics%20holding%20clamp&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS957US957&oq=electronics%20holding%20clamp&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.15582j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Put the pot in the exact center of the turntable. Put the brush with wet paint in the clamp and adjust the clamp so the brush will touch the pot at the height where you want the stripe. As the turntable spins, bring the clamp with the brush close to the spinning pot.
Experiment with other items so you learn how much paint to put on the brush, how far the paint will hold out, how wide a line will be painted, etc.

Comment: hmmm have not use any of these before turntable or a holding clamp.. now how the turntable will spin ,, do it need a generator or it will be manually set?

Comment: You could get a motorized turntable: an old record player might work. Or wrap a string several times around a manual turntable and pull the string at a reasonable speed.

Comment: use a lazy susan

Answer (score 1):

Build a structure from common materials, i.e., books, blocks of wood, etc., at the height necessary to match your objective line. You can use a pencil secured to the structure, making contact with the pot, rotating manually the pot, scribing each line as required.

At that point, you can trust your steady hand, or use the line to apply masking tape.

It's a modification of Triplefault's method with fewer materials and purchase expenses.

Duplicated in [Arts and Crafts SE](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10935/how-i-can-draw-a-horizontal-line-on-my-plaster-jar-using-paining-tape-or-stenci/10936#10936), but better suited there.